# Average distance between two nodes in a weighted undirected tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, undirected-graph

Hello I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the average distance between two nodes in a weighted undirected graph. Furthermore, this graph is a tree so it has V - 1 edges.

I thought about using Floyd Warshall to compute all-shortest paths and then calculate the average. But that would turn out to be in O(E^3) time complexity. And it really isn't enough.

I've also been thinking of using Dynamic Programming to solve it but I can't really see how...
Can anyone give me a few pointers please? I don't want a direct answer, just a few tips so that I can keep thinking about it :)

Comment: floyd warshal is dynamic programming btw

Comment: True, but it isn't fast enough for a graph with V > 1000

Comment: I didn't mean to say that .

Comment: if you found it in a programming site, can you please give it's link? We some friends found this to be interesting too.

Comment: Hello, I found it on a french website so it won't be in English. Apparently, there is a solution in O(V) with a single DFS.

Comment: Me and a friend of mine today accidentally found a O(V) solution. So we were looking forward to submitting that

Comment: Well done, what is your strategy? I though about calculating for each vertice , in how many paths it is used. But I have trouble implementing it

Comment: Think about every edge, and yes, how many times it's used.If a tree is of size N, and for an edge connecting a parent and child,the size of child subtree is P, then this edge is used P*(N-P) times

Comment: Yup, this sounds right, I'll try to implement it and I'll tell you if it works !

Answer (score 0):

Build and maintain a table of all shortest paths (no surprise).  Each entry includes the lowest-known cost and the path.

Start the table by filling in all the edges (only paths of length 1); the other entries are `inf`.

Iterate through the table, considering two cases: add a node on the left, and add a node on the right.  At each end, consider only the nodes reachable by a single edge from the end node.  Is that path shorter than the existing entry?

For instance, assume we have an edge between nodes I and J; call it `IJ`, we also have edge JK.  Is the cost of IJ + JK less than the current entry for edge IK?  If so, replace it and record the path IJK; if not, go to the next edge/node/path.

You can iterate through all existing paths until there are no updates.  Perhaps better, index the paths in which each shortest path is used; that allows you to update all paths whenever a particular sub-path is improved.

Continue the process until you make a full pass over the graph with no updates.  If you maintain that sub-path index, I *think* you can do this in a only one or two passes over the graph.  I believe that this would make the process **O(E*N^2)** (on edges and nodes).

Comment: Hello, this should work but doesn't have a good enough complexity :/